# aframe adjust camera rotation on mobile

Tags: aframe

Using Aframe how I can change the camera rotation manually so it works on mobile and still use look-controls?

I've tried via the html attribute like so:

```
document
  .querySelector('[camera]')
  .setAttribute('rotation', { x: 0, y: deg, z: 0 })
```

This works fine on desktop however on mobile the look-controls component seems to reset the camera rotation to previous value.

I've setup a demo the issue here, which changes rotation & disables look-controls. Then I set a timeout which re-ables look-controls after 1 sec. https://embed.plnkr.co/WA1rKucPk0cGffrbfrTh/

Pressing any of the html buttons rotates you to a an object and disables the look-controls. 1 sec later the control are re-abled. If you try this on mobile, you'll notice the camera rotates, then 1 sec its reverts when the look-controls are enabled.

Is there some offset I need to reset on mobile too, the lookcontrols.yawObject perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Put the camera inside an entity:

```
<a-entity rotation="0 0 0">
    <a-camera></a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Then rotate the entity instead of the camera.

Comment: Just a warning - this didn't really work for me because it messed up the spin axis of the look controls, for example spinning horizontally was not parallel to the 'ground' plane any more but off on an angle, which resulted in weird UX. It may solve the problem in certain cases (fixed camera, perhaps), but in general I think it will not solve the problem the way most interactive applications need it to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the look-controls.js a little bit to make it works,because when on mobile it will not get rotation attribute from the camera entity

function `updateOrientation` in look-controls.js：

```
if (sceneEl.isMobile) {
   // On mobile, do camera rotation with touch events and sensors.
   rotation.x = radToDeg(hmdEuler.x) + radToDeg(pitchObject.rotation.x);
   rotation.y = radToDeg(hmdEuler.y) + radToDeg(yawObject.rotation.y);
   rotation.z = radToDeg(hmdEuler.z);
}
```